# 422 error on FastAPI but data sent was according to the schema that I used

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Here is a curl request from the fastapi's interactive docs

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/?api_key=stringstring' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'images_property={
  "text": "string",
  "characteristics": "string",
  "permissions": "public"
},{
  "text": "string",
  "characteristics": "string",
  "permissions": "public"
}' \
  -F 'images=@Screen Shot 2021-04-27 at 5.06.23 PM.png;type=image/png' \
  -F 'images=@Screen Shot 2021-04-27 at 5.06.23 PM.png;type=image/png'
```

This is my function header and my model

```
class ImagesProperty(BaseModel):

    text: str = Field(max_length=256)
    characteristics: str = Field(max_length=256)
    permissions: Optional[PermissionsEnum] = Field(
        PermissionsEnum.public.value)


@router.post("/add/")
async def add_images(api_key: str, images_property: List[ImagesProperty], images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
```

From my curl request I don't know why it's always a dict, I thought it should start with any array but it never does and I don't know why

I should get a 200 but instead I get 422 from my `ImagesProperty` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why, it's because you're not allowed to have request bodies in the same header as a file or form request because of a limitation in the HTTP protocol.
[image]

Comment: so how did you overcome it?

Comment: As the image above shows you can't have `multipart/form-data` with `application/json` so `async def add_images(api_key: str, images_property: List[ImagesProperty], images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):` becomes `async def add_images(images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):` additional information is collected through the URL